# Adding elemnts in a list/array of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following code in which i want to calculate the sum of wages in Departament of sales, but it appears to have an error

```
ang = [{'Id':1, 'Name':'John', 'Wage':1000, 'Dept':'Sales'},
     {'Id':2, 'Name':'Greg', 'Wage':1200, 'Dept':'Sales'},
     {'Id':3, 'Name':'Mary', 'Wage':3000, 'Dept':'Mgmt'},
     {'Id':4, 'Name':'Paul', 'Wage':900, 'Dept':'Sales'},
     {'Id':5, 'Name':'Lily', 'Wage':1200, 'Dept':'Finance'} ]
    d='Sales'
    s = 0
    for i in ang:
        if(i['Dept']=='Sales')
            s=s+i['Wage']
    print('Total wage for sales departament.', d, '=', s)
```

Comment: The error message matters

Comment: I agree; it does appear to have an error. Do you have a *question* about that error? Were you able to figure out where the error is? If not, my recommendation is that you start by *reading* the error message.

Answer (score 0):

'Wage' key isn't on first element in your list (raising a key error), use the .get() method to find the 'Wage' and return it's value or return a default value to sum.

```
s = 0
for i in ang:
  if i.get('Dept') == 'Sales':
    s += i.get('Wage', 0) # zero as default value
```

A shorten way to do it:

```
s = sum([i.get('Wage', 0) for i in ang if i.get('Dept') == 'Sales'])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is that your piece of code calculates the total wage for all departaments and i want only for the sales departament

Comment: @OtiliaDomnea I didn't noticed that, I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the top entry has no `Wage` key, you are most likely getting a KeyError when you use `i['Wage']`. Use `i.get(<key>, <default>)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first entry in your list specifies `Salariu` instead of `Wage`.  If you fix that this works:

```
>>> ang = [{'Id':1, 'Name':'John', 'Wage':1000, 'Dept':'Sales'},
...      {'Id':2, 'Name':'Greg', 'Wage':1200, 'Dept':'Sales'},
...      {'Id':3, 'Name':'Mary', 'Wage':3000, 'Dept':'Mgmt'},
...      {'Id':4, 'Name':'Paul', 'Wage':900, 'Dept':'Sales'},
...      {'Id':5, 'Name':'Lily', 'Wage':1200, 'Dept':'Finance'} ]
>>> d = "Sales"
>>> print(f"Total wage for {d} department = {sum(a['Wage'] for a in ang if a['Dept'] == d)}")
Total wage for Sales department = 3100
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should do what you want, assuming the 'Salariu' in ID1 is intentional.

It looks like there is a missing colon (:) on the if statement though

```
if(i['Dept']=='Sales'):
    s=s+i['Wage']
```

If you're still stuck please copy the error to give us all a clue!!